# python xgboost model.feature_importances_ vs model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='gain')

Tags: python, xgboost

When I use these two codes, I got different results. But I can't find any explanation in the documentation. Anyone could help with that? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.